# Adding multiple JPanel classes from Array only shows latest

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have created a picture class (PicPanel) that extends JPanel, I create an PicPanel[] pics; which I fill with new PicPanel classes.
With a loop i add these classes to a frame but only the last picture will show.

```
    private void picStore(String[] filePaths)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.length; i++)
        {
            pics[i] = new PicPanel(filePaths[i], randomizeCords());
            this.add(pics[i]);
        }
   }
```

this is the paintComponent that i use:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    //super.paintComponent(g);

    Image image = pic.getImage();
    double scaleFactor = (double)image.getWidth(null)/(double)image.getHeight(null);

    g.drawImage(pic.getImage(), loc.x, loc.y, (int)(100 * scaleFactor), 100, null);
}
```

Comment: What layout manager are you using? I'm guessing it's the default which means you are placing every PicPanel in the center of a BorderLayout, one on top of the other. Consider using a different layout manager if this is your problem.

Comment: Yes I'm using the default one, but I'm also using randomized cordinates which at least places the last picture randomly on the screen everytime I start the program. I also use different sizes on the pictures so they should not overlap completly

Comment: You were still right TakenDarkk, I changed to CardLayout and everything worked

Comment: Good to hear. Happy coding!